# Angular omitting zeroes in a number field parsing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a number field input in a mobile app.
Because a number is needed and the digit keyboard is large and comfortable for the user.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="num" />
```

However during parsing, Angular treats numbers like `0123` as `123`.
Probably they use the standard js parsing function.

Can I get the real value in the controller somehow and parse it on my own?

Appreciate any workaround and solution, BR.

Comment: Can you use a `type="text"` and then parse the string yourself?  That would probably be the simplest way to go.

Comment: Yes I can, but the text keyboard is very uncomfortable compared to the digit one.

Comment: How about `type="tel"` or `<input type="text" pattern="\d*">` ?

Comment: Yeah, `type="tel"` is a satisfying compromise the `0` aren't omitted and it has numeric keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Use input `type="text"` with the pattern `pattern="[0-9]*"`, this will bring up the numeric keyboard on most phones and tablets. Input type text will prevent the leading 0 to be cut off.

http://jsfiddle.net/L6dqpqpe/

**EDIT**

Below is a screenshot from my phone (iOS8) so that you can see that it works. Would be great if someone could add a screenshot for android, since I don't android devices.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVXFr.png

Comment: `this will bring up the numeric keyboard on most phones and tablets` Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @null Yeah, but its pretty outdated and this only states for iOS. New android phones work with the pattern now too.

http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't apply to the device targeted having Android 4.1.2 and also to Android 4.4 or at least on the devices I've tested it on. Thank you for your kind help, this might be very helpful in future.